# How do I replace text from second capture group

Tags: vim, vsvim

I have attributes in a c# file like so, all are gauranteed to be on their own line

```
        [DataType("Checkbox")]
        public bool SomeCheckBox { get; set; }

        [DataType("Text")]
        public string SomeText { get; set; }
```

Using VSVIM I want to do a search and replace so that the code looks like this

```
        [DataType(Control.Checkbox)]
        public bool SomeCheckBox { get; set; }

        [DataType(Control.Text)]
        public string SomeText { get; set; }
```

I tested this pattern in regex101 and it seemed to worked, but can't seem to translate it into VSVIM.  VSVIM says the pattern didn't match anything.

```
%s/(?<=\[DataType\(").*?(?="\)\])/[DataType(Control.\1)]/g
```

**Basically I want to remove the quotes and prefix the second capture group with** `Control.`.

Comment: `%s/"\(.*\)"/Control.\1`

Comment: maybe you need to use `\?` instead of `?`